# Maximum-Likelihood Estimator of PDF involving sine function

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I am quite perplexed by the following problem. The usual log-likelihood route with differentiation doesn't work since it gave me a very small value for 'a'(approximately -225).
This is because I am working with logs having sines as arguments. So the optimization routine that I am using might not cope.
This problem is as follows:
[image]

I think that I need to plot a graph of L against a and find where the maximum lies. However I'm not sure what I need to do next.

Comment: You have got the critical point equation, so maybe now try [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: So I have to plot a graph of L against a, and see where the maximum lies example [3.5,3.6] and use the Newton's method?

Comment: Yes, since the likelihood here is unidimensional, plotting it is a good method ...

Comment: Maybe you landed at $\hat{a}=-225$ because you didn't restrict the range of possible values for $a$.  Given the data (with $\min(x)>0$) the range of possible values of $a$ is $0\leq a\leq \frac{\pi }{\max (x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{\pi/a}$, that implies that $0\leq a\leq \pi/\max(x)^2$.  With your data the maximum data value is 1.0953 and therefore $0\leq a\leq 2.61869$.  The plots of $\log(L)$ and $\partial \log(L)/\partial a$ should look like the following:

[image: logL vs a]

[image: Derivative of logL with respect to a]

So the maximum likelihood estimate should be around 2.1.

**Obtaining the maximum likelihood estimate with *R***

```
# Data
  x <- c(0.7533, 0.7777, 0.789, 0.7329, 0.7766, 1.0383, 1.0953, 1.0278, 1.0706, 
    0.9697, 1.0689, 0.5881, 1.0548, 1.0155, 0.6369, 1.0489, 1.0948, 1.0415, 0.7556)

# Log of the likelihood function
  logL <- function(a, x) {
    n <- length(x)
    n*log(a) + sum(log(x)) + sum(log(sin(a*x^2)))
  }
  
# Maximum likelihood estimate using optimize
  (mle <- optimize(logL, c(0, pi/max(x)^2), x=x, maximum=TRUE))
  
# Maximum likelihood estimate using optim
  aInit <- 2
  mle <- optim(aInit, logL, x=x, control=list(fnscale=-1), method="Brent",
    lower=0, upper=pi/max(x)^2, hessian=TRUE)
  mle$par
  # [1] 2.082155
  mle$value
  # [1] 7.411797
  # Standard error of the estimate
  (se <- as.numeric((-1/mle$hessian)^0.5))
  # [1] 0.1731848
```

**Obtaining the maximum likelihood estimate with *Mathematica***

```
x = {0.7533, 0.7777, 0.789, 0.7329, 0.7766, 1.0383, 1.0953, 1.0278, 
   1.0706, 0.9697, 1.0689, 0.5881, 1.0548, 1.0155, 0.6369, 1.0489, 
   1.0948, 1.0415, 0.7556};
n = Length[x];
(* Log likelihood *)
logL = n Log[a] + Total[Log[x]] + Total[Log[Sin[a x^2]]];
(* First derivative *)
dlogLa = n/a + Total[x^2 Cot[a x^2]];

(* Find maximum likelihood estimate *)
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, 0 < a < Pi/Max[x]^2}, {{a, 2}}]
(* {7.4118, {a -> 2.08215}} *)

(* Approximate standard error using the Delta Method *)
(* Second derivative *)
dlogLa2 = D[dlogLa, a];
se = (-1/dlogLa2 /. mle[[2]])^0.5
(* 0.173185 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It really helped me understand better. Now my problem is to find the exact value of the estimator.

Comment: Will you be using R or Mathematica?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!